# Creating a semivariogram in R starting from a GeoTiff file

Tags: r, gstat, covariogram

I'm  trying to create a semivariogram in R, giving it data from a raster coming from a GeoTif file.
The version of Rstudio I'm running is the "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for Windows and my OS is windows 10 home.

The variogram function from the `gstat` package is giving me this error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘gridded’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

My lines of code were:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(gstat)
A <- raster("C:/Users/Mark/EX.tif",5) #to create a raster from the fith layer of EX.tif
ptA <- rasterToPoints(A) #to extract the coordinates 
dfA <- as.data.frame(A) #to convert the raster A as a dataframe
v <- gstat::variogram(object = EX_1~1, locations = ptA, data = dfA)
```

I expected to create a variogram object, obtained that error message.

I hope to finally understand the variogram function, what kind of data it needs as input and how to give this input obtaining it from a GeoTif file.

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example. check out [how to to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: also: use `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")` at the beginning of your code to get the error in english

Comment: Ok, I followed your answer to change the language of the environment to english,, now the error message is:                                                                                         
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gridded’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Comment: I'll be reading the data on your link on how to make a reproducible example and I will edit my question as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

the error means that the input class is not correct. you should include a gstat object as input, not a dataframe.
Try to transform your dataframe to a spatial object, then calculate the semivariogram:

coordinates(dfA)= ~ x + y

v <- gstat::variogram(object = EX_1 ~1, data = dfA)